# Has the Bifrost ever been used as a weapon?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel, weapon

It was stated that the Bifrost has, at full power, enough power to destroy an entire planet, and we do see it wreaking havoc upon Jotunheim when Loki unleashes it against that realm during the first *Thor* movie.

With the exception of that use of the Bifrost by Loki, are there any known uses of the Bifrost by the Asgardians as a weapon against their enemies, rather than a transportation mechanism to transport between realms?

Comment: this is such a good question I was positive I had seen in before, but nope. +1

Comment: @MikeEdenfield I thought I saw it before as well, but I looked and didn't find it, so meh.  Thought I'd ask, as well, due to curiosity :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### No, the Bifrost dimensional bridging and projection system, has not been shown being used as a weapon in the Thor movies.

- The Bifrost as a weapon system originated in the Thor movies and may have only recently be retconned into comic lore. Before that, the Bifrost was merely a magical means of moving among the Nine Realms giving the Asgardians access to every location save those blocked by magical or advanced technological means.
- I suspect the Asgardians agree to NOT use it as such in exchange for the ability to come and go in other realms without censure. Its presence is apparently easily detectable with the right magic or technology and would leave a significant signature should it be used as such. That signature would point back to Asgard as the point of origin and thus implicate them as a violator of whatever truce allows the Nine Realms to coexist in relative peace.

Comment: Interesting, I thought they would have had additional references to it as a destructive force of power, but maybe it was added to further the plotline of *Thor* a little further.  They certainly did that well.  Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Given the references to the Einstein-Rosen Bridge theories, the creation of an unregulated or uncontrolled wormhole would be tantamount to the forces seen in a singularity, the capacity to destroy worlds is implied within its abilities. Don't use it to transport matter, just use it as a singularity and paint with a wormhole. No planet could survive this for long at the highest settings.

Comment: If it does have enough power to destroy a planet, I doubt there'll be anyone around to be tracing the signature back to its origin.